# How semijoin is different from natural join + projection?

Tags: sql, relational, relational-algebra

How semijoin is different from natural join + projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't. A semijoin can be defined as a projection on a natural join.

See [Wikipedia: Relational algebra / Semijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29)